# Can you marry me? vs Will you marry me?

Tags: will-would, can-could

I'm having a hard time explaining to my students "Can you marry me?" is not the right question to ask while proposing to someone.

Likewise; "Will you dance with me?" sounds perfectly natural while "Can you dance with me?" sounds unnatural to my ears and I cannot tell why.

Is there a hard rule to apply when choosing between "Will" and "Can(or Could)" in such circumstances?

Comment: Simply put, a question starting 'can you...' enquires about ability or permission; a question starting 'will you...' is a request, or enquires about future plans. In informal speech, we often start requests with 'can you...', e.g. 'can you please open the window?', but a proposal of marriage has a special fixed form.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Associating 'will' with 'Future plans' will do. And what do you think of 'Can you dance with me?'? Would a native speaker ever ask such a question? If yes, how can I explain the difference between them?

Comment: You need to understand that 'will you marry me?' is usually spoken as a formal proposal of marriage. To call it an enquiry about future plans is inaccurate. It's not like asking 'will you take a vacation next year?', or 'will your office be open on Saturday?'. One might ask 'can you dance with me?' meaning 'are you free to dance with me?' if there was an issue of ability, for example if the other person might have already promised the next dance to someone else.

Comment: Even native English speakers may not realize that "Will you marry me?" is an archaic use of language whose meaning is not what it appears to be at first glance. The expression hearkens back to before constructions with "do" as an auxiliary verb became common. Therefore, the real meaning of the expression in contemporary language is, very logically, "Do you want to marry me?", not "Are you going to marry me?" "Will" in this instance is used as a synonym for "want", which is itself an archaicism.

Comment: 'Can' and 'could' (the more polite synonym here) are often used in polite requests, as @Michael says, so synonymously with 'would' ('will' can sound too abrupt): "Can / could / would you pass the doughnuts, please, Jo(./?) ) But these don't work with big asks (??"Could you just swim across to France and get me some Camembert, Jo. / *"Can you just marry me tomorrow, please, Divina?"). A more reverential form of words is required, not the everyday. "Could I possibly ask you to check the path for landmines / teach 5z on Friday afternoon?" / "Will you ...?"